# smooth edges when removing background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I removed the Background of this image : 
[image]

and colored the black and red areas with brush tool, the result I got has sharp edges :

[image]

how can I make the edges smoother like the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to Illustrator, I'd say try doing an image trace of that.

But in Photoshop, here's one way to improve your situation: Once you have your desired shapes selected, try using the `Select > Select and Mask` function and adjust settings to smooth out your selection. (Note: in older versions of Photoshop, this may be called `Refine Edge')

Once you have it selected, you can what you want with it. Hopefully that helps.

[image]